# Cakephp: Loading background-image css

Tags: php, css, html, cakephp, mod-rewrite

I'm not getting loading a background-image on my page..It's inside "app/webroot/img/background.png"

style.css - Its working.. I just can not load my image

```
.layout{
    width: 100%;
    height: 230px;  
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    background-image:('../img/background.png');
}

.layout-image{
    width: 940px;
    height: 230px;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
}
```

index.php

```
<div class="layout">
      <div class="layout-image">
          <img src="img/layout.png" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
```

webroot/.htacces

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry for my stupid mistake, missed url

```
background-image: url('../img/background.png');
```

Comment: Just shy of ten years later, your "stupid" mistake has helped more than a thousand people--being conservative. Happens even to the best of us. You live and learn.